# posthoc tests from function "phytools::phylANOVA" generating tables full of NA values

Tags: phylogeny, posthoc

I have a factor with 9 categories (`Biome`), a numeric variable(`visual`) and a pruned phylogenetic tree (`pruned.tree`) with all species involved in these two variables. I have the next line:

`phyl_phytools<-phylANOVA(pruned.tree,Biome,visual, posthoc=TRUE, p.adj=c("holm"))`

But, I obtain the next output:

```
ANOVA table: Phylogenetic ANOVA

Response: y
           Sum Sq   Mean Sq  F value Pr(>F)
x        107.1753 13.396912 2.829053  0.008
Residual 644.0247  4.735476                

P-value based on simulation.
---------

Pairwise posthoc test using method = "holm"

Pairwise t-values:
    1 10 13 14  2  3  4  7  9
1  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
13 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
14 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
9  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Pairwise corrected P-values:
    1 10 13 14  2  3  4  7  9
1  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
13 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
14 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
9  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong in posthoc tests to get these NA values instead of p-values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe because one of the p-value is an NA and the applied correction does not use `na.rm = TRUE`? Although it's very hard to figure out without a reproducible example. I suggest you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help understanding what's going on.

Comment: I solved the problem. It seems the function does not accept groups with n=1.